# pd.DataFrame cuts the decimals' mantissa

Tags: pandas, dataframe, decimal, mantissa

Need to convert list of values with long mantissa into pd.DataFrame without precision lost:

[image]

My list of decimals:

[image]

The way pd.DataFrame convert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values are stored with the correct precision, they are just truncated when you display them.

You can change the precision used by pandas when displaying datarames by using `pd.set_option('display.precision', num_decimal_digits)`.

For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([0.123456789])

print('Before setting precision:')
print(df)
pd.set_option('display.precision', 9)
print('After setting precision:')
print(df)
```

prints

```
Before setting precision:
          0
0  0.123457
After setting precision:
             0
0  0.123456789
```